# WiFi: Unable to connect to any network

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 with all updates and Intel AX200 which seems to be recognized out of the box. As far as I can see this device should work out of the box starting from kernel 5.1, I'm on 5.4 and it works, but I can not connect to any network - I am entering the correct password and then the prompt is back after timeout.

I tried my home WiFi which works for my other computer, few laptops (all Linux) and few Phones. As a sanity check I also tried to create a WiFi hotspot from my phone but have the same problem connecting to it.

Here is some output.

`uname -sr`

```
Linux 5.4.0-31-generic
```

`lspci -knn` (relevant part)

```
2d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
DeviceName: RTL8111EPV
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:0084]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

`dmesg` after connection attempt

```
[  109.535290] wlo1: authenticate with 90:5c:44:ef:12:8c
[  109.538454] wlo1: send auth to 90:5c:44:ef:12:8c (try 1/3)
[  109.562154] wlo1: authenticated
[  109.565795] wlo1: associate with 90:5c:44:ef:12:8c (try 1/3)
[  109.571286] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 90:5c:44:ef:12:8c (capab=0x1511 status=17 aid=8774)
[  109.571289] wlo1: 90:5c:44:ef:12:8c denied association (code=17)
[  109.707690] wlo1: authenticate with 90:5c:44:ef:12:60
[  109.709675] wlo1: send auth to 90:5c:44:ef:12:60 (try 1/3)
[  110.323973] iwlwifi 0000:2d:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[  110.324007] wlo1: Connection to AP 90:5c:44:ef:12:60 lost
[  110.741987] wlo1: send auth to 90:5c:44:ef:12:60 (try 2/3)
[  111.356240] iwlwifi 0000:2d:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[  111.356328] wlo1: Connection to AP 90:5c:44:ef:12:60 lost
[  111.510070] wlo1: send auth to 90:5c:44:ef:12:60 (try 3/3)
[  112.124315] iwlwifi 0000:2d:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[  112.124402] wlo1: Connection to AP 90:5c:44:ef:12:60 lost
[  112.501653] wlo1: authentication with 90:5c:44:ef:12:60 timed out
[  113.167325] wlo1: authenticate with 90:5c:44:ef:12:8c
[  113.169701] wlo1: send auth to 90:5c:44:ef:12:8c (try 1/3)
[  113.193272] wlo1: authenticated
[  113.193622] wlo1: associate with 90:5c:44:ef:12:8c (try 1/3)
[  113.199120] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 90:5c:44:ef:12:8c (capab=0x1511 status=17 aid=9240)
[  113.199122] wlo1: 90:5c:44:ef:12:8c denied association (code=17)
[  114.246064] wlo1: authenticate with 90:5c:44:ef:12:8c
[  114.249091] wlo1: send auth to 90:5c:44:ef:12:8c (try 1/3)
[  114.272630] wlo1: authenticated
[  114.273601] wlo1: associate with 90:5c:44:ef:12:8c (try 1/3)
[  114.279087] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 90:5c:44:ef:12:8c (capab=0x1511 status=17 aid=0)
[  114.279090] wlo1: 90:5c:44:ef:12:8c denied association (code=17)
[  124.939349] wlo1: authenticate with 90:5c:44:ef:12:60
[  124.942238] wlo1: send auth to 90:5c:44:ef:12:60 (try 1/3)
[  125.556483] iwlwifi 0000:2d:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[  125.556692] wlo1: Connection to AP 90:5c:44:ef:12:60 lost
[  125.685931] wlo1: send auth to 90:5c:44:ef:12:60 (try 2/3)
[  126.300210] iwlwifi 0000:2d:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[  126.300254] wlo1: Connection to AP 90:5c:44:ef:12:60 lost
[  126.518729] wlo1: send auth to 90:5c:44:ef:12:60 (try 3/3)
[  127.132869] iwlwifi 0000:2d:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[  127.132929] wlo1: Connection to AP 90:5c:44:ef:12:60 lost
[  127.509891] wlo1: authentication with 90:5c:44:ef:12:60 timed out
```

Does the community know what might be wrong here? What can I do to make it right?

Comment: The return in the [handshake](https://www.wifi-professionals.com/2019/01/4-way-handshake) doesn't seem to be occurring. You don't have multiple unique devices broadcasting the same SSID, do you? Also pay attention to the deny error - [this is a common](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1307351) event which might not be device related.

Comment: @DankyNanky the SSID is unique, as for the other problem - I don't have many connected devices and didn't have much network activity. In any case I tried to rule out problems with that particular router by trying it with the hotspot from my phone, got the same result. 
Still something I tried to google around, only found some old threads and not one that is really similar, weird.

Answer (score 0):

So, I kind of solved it by limiting the 2.4 Ghz channel with 20 Mhz on my router.

I also looked at network manager logs and compared them with dmesg as posted above and it seemed that everything was working but the signal was too weak, it works with limited channel width though it's about 10-20 times slower then on my other computer nearby adn I still wasn't able to connect to my phone.

And then I got that idea about signal being weak and noticed I have an external antenna that was not connected (it's a new computer).  With antenna connected it works perfectly, so It's not that tricky, it's just an issue with me overthinking a simple problem :)